# Deafen Members and Whisper command on discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py, bots

I'm trying to build a "whisper" system on my discord bot, to make a shortcut to deafen and undeafen some members on the channel.

Right now, this is my code:

```
from typing import Optional
from discord import Member
from discord.ext.commands import Cog, Greedy
from discord.ext.commands import CheckFailure
from discord.ext.commands import command, has_permissions, bot_has_permissions, MissingPermissions

from ..db import db

class Mod(Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @command(description = 'I will deafen the person mentioned, Restriction to GM role', name = 'deaf')
    @bot_has_permissions(administrator = True, manage_roles=True, deafen_members = True)
    async def deaf_members(self, ctx, targets: Greedy[Member], *, reason: Optional[str] = 'The master is whispering!'):
        if targets (deafen = False):
            await targets.edit(deafen = True)
            await ctx.send(f"{targets.mention} can't hear anymore")


    @Cog.listener()
    async def on_ready(self):
        if not self.bot.ready:
            self.bot.cogs_ready.ready_up('mod')

def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(Mod(bot))
```

The problem that I'm having is that everytime that I try to run the command, it says that I'm missing `deafen_members` permissions. But I already gave it administrator permissions, both in the code and in the bot dev page.
I hope that you could help me, and if possible, someone could explain to me how can I deafen everyone except the people that I want to send the message, to make a quality of life from this command.

Comment: The bot needs the permissions in the _server_. The code permissions are to make sure only certain people (and servers) can use it. The dev portal permissions is to create the link with the permissions you chose (the link is the link you use to invite bots to servers)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help, I actually tried this. T've created a role with the permissions and applied to the bot. I also tried to change the permissions on the dev portal generating a whole new link, But I still been getting the same error. "discord.ext.commands.errors.BotMissingPermissions: Bot requires Deafen Members permission(s) to run this command."

Comment: Are you sure? Double check. This shouldn't happen at all otherwise.

Comment: Yeah, double check it now, same error man. I can't see why is not working, even when I'm giving all the permissions requested, throug the connection link, through the dev site and through the code.

Comment: Hm. Did you add the permissions to the bot's role? Or add an administrator role to the bot in the server?

Comment: I add a permission to the bot role, and an admin permission to the bot in the server. The bot role has just the admin, and deafen members permission.